# I am writing 0 to 255 ascii character and trying to read it character by characte but cant read after 25th character

Tags: c++

Here is the code snippet:

```
int main()
{
  char ch=26;
  ofstream fout;
  fout.open("key.txt");
  if (fout.is_open())
  {
    for(int i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
      ch=i;
      fout << ch;
      cout<<ch;
    }
    fout.close();
  }
  else
    cout << "Unable to open file";
  string line;
  ifstream fout1 ("key.txt");
  if (fout1.is_open())
  {
    while (fout1)
    {
      fout1.get(ch);
      cout <<" "<< (int)ch<<" "<<ch<<"\t ";
    }
    fout1.close();
  }
  else
    cout << "Unable to open file";
  return 0;
}
```

I found out that while reading 26th character it stops program. If it is escaped then all others are read. Note I am using Code Blocks IDE.

Comment: Please post the code you use to read and write.

Comment: Note that ASCII doesn't *have* 256 characters. It stops at 126 or 127, depending on how strictly you're defining it.

Comment: extended ascii character are from 0 - 255

Comment: Ascii stops at 127.  Extended ascii is an oxymoron.

Comment: Even so, the first 31 characters aren't directly printable. TAB, CR and LF are somewhat reasonable, but STX? NUL?

Comment: @punitshah: Nonsense. There's no such thing as "extended ASCII". There's only ASCII and everything else that is not ASCII.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by the C++11 tag on this question - there's nothing specifically C++11 about it at all and I suspect if I wrote an answer that was specifically C++11 it wouldn't be what you were looking for in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you can't read the 26th character is because its value is 26. And that is interpreted in textfiles as an end-of-file marker. You must open your file as binary ,then it will work.

Comment: It's an EOF marker if you're on the DOS or Windows platform. Not sure if other platforms treat it as EOF.

Answer (score 2):

In the code shown, I suggest you close the output file first, before opening it for reading. This will make sure that any characters in the buffer is flushed to disk. Also, after reading you might want to flush `cout` as well, if the program doesn't end there.

Also note that some characters are not printable, or do weird things when printed (like jumping to the beginning of the line, or deleting whats already being printed).